# How a column which has constraint "UNIQUE" is accepting duplicate values in mysql -server 5.7

Tags: mysql

The problem is I set the constraint "UNIQUE"to column "hobby" of a existing table "info". And when i added a new entry by using this syntax:

```
 mysql> update info
    -> set hobby="HACKING"
    -> where name = "TAYLOR";
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.08 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
```

It's get added without any error. How is this possible when i already added a "UNIQUE" constraint on "hobby"?
Here is all details of Table:

```
mysql> select * from info;
+-----+-----------+---------+-------+-----------+
| id  | name      | address | marks | hobby     |
+-----+-----------+---------+-------+-----------+
| 501 | JAMES     | DELHI   |   100 | GOLF      |
| 502 | TAYLOR    | MUMBAI  |    58 | HACKING   |
| 503 | MARTIN    | GOA     |    98 | CHESS     |
| 504 | ROBIN     | HARYANA |    68 | LUDO      |
| 505 | VIRAT     | UP      |    48 | CRICKET   |
| 506 | GAYLE     | MP      |    58 | cricket   |
| 507 | PRINCE    | KERALA  |    63 | ADVENTURE |
| 508 | ANONYMOUS | USA     |    72 | HACKING
  |
+-----+-----------+---------+-------+-----------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

    mysql> show create table info;
    +-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    | Table | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        |
    +-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    | info  | CREATE TABLE `info` (
      `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
      `address` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
      `marks` int(65) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
      `hobby` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
      UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`,`hobby`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=509 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
    +-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

You can see "ANONYMOUS", "TAYLOR" and "VIRAT", "GAYLE" have same hobby "HACKING" and "CRICKET" respectively.
how is this happening?

Comment: the ANONYMOUS", "TAYLOR" and "VIRAT", "GAYLE" values have diffent id .. your unique constraint is non id, hobby .. not hobby only

Comment: @scaisEdge Yes, both "id" and "hobby" are unique but "id" is primary key. So id is okay as it should. But why hobby has duplicate values?

Comment: becuase you have not an unique constraints on hobby  .. but on (id and bobby)

Comment: @scaisEdge id and hobby means both right?

Comment: yes  .. you have  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`,`hobby`)  try using an UNIQUE KEY `hobby` (``hobby`)

Comment: @scaisEdge Actually, i can't understand what id (id,hobby) means. It means i only added id as unique? `The syntax was  mysql> alter table info
    -> add constraint unique(id, hobby);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.38 sec)`
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0 . Is it wrong?

Comment: No this mean the you have added  an unique (constrains ) on the combined  values  of (id and hobby)

Comment: @scaisEdge so what should be correct syntax if i want to add both at once?

Comment: is not clear to me  .. you want the unique constraints on hobby only  ??? not on (id, hobby) ??

Comment: @scaisEdge i  want on both but not on their "combined values".

Comment: simply add a unique constraint for hobby  .. (the id is alredy unique by the primary key)

Comment: @scaisEdge i am asking in general, if i have to make any two or more columns unique what would be the syntax?

Comment: i have posted and asnwer  hope is clear (and useful)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you need  a primary key on id but also the unique value for hobby and name you could use the unique constraints for both hobby and name columns eg:

```
CREATE TABLE `info` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `marks` int(65) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `hobby` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uk_hobby` (`hobby`), 
  UNIQUE KEY `uk_name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=509 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: what is 'uk' in hobby?